# How can I create a shared memory region which can expand over time?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I need to work with an old C++ project where each process loads the same data into the memory. This is read-only and each process has the exact same copy of the data. Of late the service has started thrashing the system that it runs on.

I was evaluating ways in which I could make changes to this and I think `boost interprocess` libraries are a good fit for my use case. Another thing that I considered was the use of an external data store but due to the latencies I'm not too inclined to use that.

I had a look at the `boost` apis and they seem to require us to specify the size of the shared memory region. In my case this won't be constant as the volume of data that needs to be loaded in grows over time. Is this shared memory resizable?

Also feel free to suggest alternative suggestions to the problem or your experiences with `boost interprocess` in similar situations.

Comment: Not saying you can't do that, but how would the process using the shared memory know that it has grown? Would it be possible to use multiple region and add more region(s) when you need more space? I'm not at all familiar with the "boost" libraries for this, so I can't say.

Comment: @MatsPetersson In the simplest case, you could use something similar to a `vector` that recorded its `size` and `capacity`.

Comment: It would still require the applications using the data to "check if it's grown" or some such. I still think there are several possible solutions, not all of which are related to "growing" the size of the shared area.

Comment: I think I'll use multiple regions based on the logical group they will represent. But again each group(shared memory region) could individually grow.

Answer (score 1):

To resize shared memory, you can use [shmctl](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/ipcshmct.htm), where `cmd=SHM_SIZE`.

You must take care when doing this. If you reduce the size, and other processes access memory beyond it's size, you will get SIGBUS signal.

Another problem is how to inform other processes that a shared memory was resized. I guess you can use a message queue, or other IPC mechanism.

Comment: @nikhil No idea. I see that it has shared_memory_object::truncate method to set the size, but I am not sure if it it allowed to resize the shared memory. Also, the size of the read-only shared memory object is passed to the constructor. You would have to recreate objects.

Comment: Oh ok, we need to call truncate only if the region can be written to. Thanks for this, I'll also read up about `shmctl`.